# How does ltrace (library tracing tool) work?

Tags: linux, trace, ltrace

How does [`ltrace`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html) work?

How does it find out which library functions a program calls?

Is there any common code path that all calls to library functions go through? Maybe `ltrace` sets breakpoints in this common code path?

Comment: Usually debugging symbols left in the compiled binary will provide function call names, program flow, etc. Stripping the binary usually removes this (making debugging harder).

Comment: `ltrace` is open source. So you could just look at the source...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dynamic executables have a symbol table used by the linker when resolving references that need to be connected to library functions. (You can see this yourself by running `objdump -T /path/to/binary`).

This symbol table is accessible by other tools -- such as `ltrace` -- as well, so it's trivial to determine which functions need to be hooked and walk that list individually.

See [a talk on ltrace internals](https://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2007/ols2007v1-pages-41-52.pdf) presented at the Ottowa Linux Symposium, which provides a detailed, function-by-function breakdown; to follow along the source, see the [official repository](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/ltrace.git), or a [third-party github mirror](https://github.com/ice799/ltrace).

Some newer releases (more recent than that talk) also hook the `dlopen()` call, to be able to trace invocation of dynamically loaded libraries as well. The mechanism there should be rather obvious on a moment's thought -- if one can replace `dlopen()` with a shim (when `dlopen()` itself is dynamically linked as above), one can then set a breakpoint on any function pointer it returns.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The symbol table is populated after executable starts, right? So ltrace is probably reading addresses from symbol table just after program starts?

Comment: `ld.so` (on Linux) performs linking and loading *before* `main()` is called. See `man ld.so`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. So ltrace must stop the program between ld.so populates the tables and main() begins to read addresses from the symbol table.

Comment: As I read the paper, it rather does the work that would otherwise be performed by `ld.so` itself, adding hooks along the way. But given as there's primary material here, you'd be better off referring to it directly. :)